# Where to place the word "combined."

Tags: grammar

Should I write "I taught a combined 50 face to face and online courses" or "I taught 50 face to face and online courses combined"?

Comment: Rewrite the sentence -- it's confusing.

Comment: I agree. I rewrote it.